# Why does this jQuery work differently after I move to a different page then hit the back button?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm making a simple navigation menu for a site.  You create an `ul` with id `menu`, and should be pretty simple from there.  I have some simple css to give all the `li`s the correct background image, then some jQuery to change the look of an `li` when the user mouses over.  It works pretty well, but there's one problem.  When the user clicks on a link  *directly*, rather than clicking in the box around it, and then uses the browser's back button, things go wrong.  When the user hovers over *this* time, the entire li goes completely blank, but it's fine once the user mouses away.  Does anyone know what may cause this strange behavior?  (Note, every once in a while, mousing over causes a `li` to flicker, especially if it's one of the bottom two `li`s.  I thought this was normal, but maybe it could be helpful in diagnosing the problem.)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Menu Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
ul#menu{width: 185px; margin: auto; text-align: center; color: #fff; list-style-type: none;}

ul,li,h2{padding: 5px 0 0 0; margin: 0;}

li h2{height: 49px; background: url('top.png'); vertical-align: middle;}
li.link{height: 30px; background: url('link.png');}
li.link a{color: white; text-decoration: none;}
li.bottom{height: 25px; background: url('bottom.png');}
</style>

<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".link").mouseover(function(){ //highlight on mouseover
   $(this).css({background: "url('file:///Users/J/Desktop/DHTML/Menu/linkselect.png')"});
  })
  $(".link").mouseout(function(){ //un-highlight on mouseout
   $(this).css({background: "url('./link.png')"});
  })
  $(".link").click(function(){ //go to site on click, even if click isn't on link
   window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
  })
 })
</script>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="menu">
 <li><h2>Menu</h2></li>
 <li class="link"><a href="http://google.com/">Google</a></li>
 <li class="link"><a href="http://norwegianrecycling.multiply.com/">Norwegian Recycling</a></li>
 <li class="link"><a href="http://www.jquery.com/">jQuery</a></li>
 <li class="link"><a href="http://www.apple.com/">Apple</a></li>
 <li class="link"><a href="http://www.ubuntu.com">Ubuntu</a></li>
 <li class="link"><a href="http://www.firefox.com/">Firefox</a></li>
 <li class="link"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/">YouTube</a></li>
 <li class="bottom"></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just tried this and it worked OK for me... what browser/OS are you using?  and what JQuery version?

Comment: Also, if you are going to make something behave like a link, you should give it the right mouse cursor:  .link { cursor: pointer; }

Comment: @Kip, then set the mousepointer using javascript, otherwise people without javascript will still see the pointer and think the whole link is a li: $('.link').css('cursor', 'pointer');

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You know you can do everything you're doing there with *just* CSS and HTML?

- Set the `a` to `display:block` so that it fills the `li`
- Set a `:hover` state on a to change the background.
- ???
- Profit.

Comment: You'll probably want to set height and line-height on the link (a, not .link) elements too.

Comment: I'm not sure that :hover will work in older browsers like IE6 while the javascript method would. That has been my experience in the past when dealing with IE6.

Comment: I don't mean to sound rude, but this is not answering his question. Offering another solution wasn't the request. I am actually curious why the behavior would be different after hitting the back-button.

Comment: From what I have read, in IE6, :hover is supported on anchors but not things like li,tr, etc.. I have to support IE6 and have had to write javascript workarounds for this.

Comment: you may be right that it only works on anchors... I, too, have the misfortune of being forced to support IE6, and we use it all the time, but probably only on anchors.

Comment: a:hover works - that's what I'm suggesting. Make the <a> a block, make it fill the <li> and give it the background instead of the <li>

Comment: IE6 does not support :hover on anything other then a. Making the a as big as the li (using lineheight and display:block as Oli suggests) should work.

Answer (score 2):

The following works. I'll leave the CSS details to you. Note also, as other have pointed out, you CAN do this with pure CSS and get the same result. But since that is not what you asked for, I will respect your request and give jQuery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Default Web Project - www.SampsonResume.com</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .ul {list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;border:1px solid #CCCCCC;}
      li.link {background-color:#000000;padding:10px;}
        li a {color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none;}
      li.on {background-color:#f1f1f1;cursor:pointer;}
        li.on a {color:#000000;}
    </style>
    <script src='scripts/jquery/jquery-1.3.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $("li.link").each(function(){
            $(this).hover(
              function(){$(this).addClass("on");},
              function(){$(this).removeClass("on");}
            );
           $(this).click(function(){
             window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
           });          
         });
       });
     </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li class="link"><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
      <li class="link"><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a></li>
      <li class="link"><a href="http://www.SampsonVideos.com">SampsonVideos</a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The "each" is completely unnecessary, isn't it?  That is what chaining is for:  $('li.link').hover(...).click(...);

Comment: I do think that this code will fix his problem though.  He needs to use the "hover" method or use the mouseenter/mouseleave events in place of mouseover/mouseout.  +1 from me!

Comment: Prestaul, I used .each() as a habit, as I generally do more with my links than merely adding classes.

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't exactly an answer to your question, but changing the CSS properties of an element when hovered can be done entirely in CSS.  For your example, your CSS would be something like:

```
.link {
  background: url('./link.png');
}
.link:hover {
  background: url('file:///Users/J/Desktop/DHTML/Menu/linkselect.png');
}
```

<del>I *think* you could also wrap the `<a>` tag around the `<li>` tag, such that the whole list item is the link (eliminating the need for the `$(".link").click(...)` code).</del>

Oops, can't wrap `<a>` around `<li>`, but as Oli mentioned, you can do this in CSS:

```
.link a {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh well, I said I wouldn't give a CSS-Solution, but here it is anyway:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Default Web Project - www.SampsonResume.com</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      ul {list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;border:1px solid #CCCCCC;}
      li {margin:0;padding:0;}
        li a {display:block;background-color:#FFF;color:#000;text-decoration:none;}
      li a:hover {color:#FFF;background-color:#000;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.SampsonVideos.com">SampsonVideos</a></li>
    </ul>

  </body>
</html>
```